# Python web interface for sensors

Tags: python, http, raspberry-pi

I have a Raspberry Pi powerd weather station with wifi interface.

The hardware is running fine, but now I face the problem to present the data in a usefull form. As it has wifi and therefore connects to my local network I wanted a webpage presenting my data.

As I am a bit lazy I looked around for existing modules and found some: Django, web2py, TurboGears, SimpleHTTPServer.
But they all seem to be not that suited for my application as they either present a simple (static) file or the "full stack" with database and what not.
But I am really looking for some framework which enables me to craft my website inside my python code and also gives me the possibility to interface with the client through ajax or something similar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/) its built for this.

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def hello():
    return "Hello World! The temp is %d" % get_temp() # imaginary temp func

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

Answer (score 0):

[Twisted](https://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/core/howto/index.html) is very good for this sort of thing. I use it to provide a web interface for a build system. You can get nice web pages with [templates](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/web/howto/twisted-templates.html), and there are some [excellent](http://jcalderone.livejournal.com/50562.html) [introductions](http://krondo.com/?page_id=1327).